# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) while developing dictionary app

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am developing a dictionary app..And I am getting this error while clicking the search icon.

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

This is a part of my code

```
Container(
           child: ListTile(
           title: Text(data.word!),
           subtitle: Text(
           data.phonetics![index].text!),
           trailing: IconButton(
             onPressed: () {
               final path = data
                .phonetics![index]
                .audio;
                  playAudio("https:$path");
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.audiotrack)),
                  ),
                ),
```

And this is the code the exception is pointing to

```
data.phonetics![index].text!
```

I am using flutter 2.5.3 Help me solve this error..Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better  using latest version of flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try accepting null on text case and check null before using `!`

```dart
Container(
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text("${data.word}"),
    subtitle: Text("${data.phonetics?[index].text}"),
    trailing: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final path = data.phonetics?[index].audio;
          if (path != null) {
            playAudio("https:$path");
          }
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.audiotrack)),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Still not working bro...Pointing to some other error. Will it work If I upgrade flutter?

Answer (score 0):

**Error Explanation:** Bang operator(!) means that in flutter, when you use this operator, you are completely sure that variable is not going to be null in any case.
As you had written `data.phonetics![index].text!`, this is the where error is generating. Now error is saying that either `phonetics` or `text` is `null`.
There are two ways to resolve this peacefully -

1. Use **if** conditional to confirm that variable is not null
2. Use **null-aware** or **if-null** operator **??** like this

```
${data.phonetics?[index].text ?? ''}
```